# Entity Manager Management

Tags: hibernate, entitymanager

How does an entity manager manage?

I was reading a couple of articles 
http://codeidol.com/java/netbeans/Persistence-EntityManager/Interacting-with-an-EntityManager/

I came across a couple of questions to ask!

After using

```
Customer cust = entityManager.find(Customer.class, 2);
```

If we in fact change the primary Id of the current customer bean,

Question 1:
Will the Entity Manager still know what to manage? Since it is using a primary key to find all the data?

Question 2: If we completely change the data and persist, which is
"act of inserting it within a database" it feels like it won't be the same, will the original object and the persisted object be the same? Is it still managed by the Entity Manager? Even though everything will get updated? Will there be two objects or one inside the database?

Just some food for thought!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever change the primary key value of a persistent entity:
  - it won't work
  - even if it did, all the foreign key constraints to this primary key would break anyway

A primary key is supposed to be immutable.